# How return Json data by calling an web-service through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a web service which returns JSON data below code I am using for calling the web service.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:5606/xyz',
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: '{"a":"b"}',
  success: function(responses, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    alert(responses);
  },
  error: function(xhr, err) {
    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
  },
  complete: function() {}
});
};
```

it return output of alert in success function as [object object] but I want it in proper json format.

Comment: use `console.log()` not `alert`

Comment: but I want the response values for calling another webservice

Comment: That's the point. You get JSON data, don't `alert` it, just log it in your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

use `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`

**Example:**

```
var response = {};

response.status ="success";
response.data="Your data";

alert(response); //It will give you [object object]
console.log(response); //Gives JSON data in console
alert(JSON.stringify(response)); //Alerts json string

if(response.status == "success")
  //Pass response.data to the next webservice it will still be in the json format.
```

Comment: My response is `{"responses":[{"coordinate_search":{"actions":[]},"took":67,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":15500,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"2":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":263731936070,"doc_count":34},{"key":263735261942,"doc_count":26}`
in this I want only values present under "Key"

Comment: You mean key property inside buckets?

Comment: $.each(response.aggregations.2.bucket,function(key,value) 
   {
   if(key == 'key')
        value.key; //Get the key value here
   }
   );

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number when I am using it like
`success: function (data) {
     numbers=JSON.stringify((data.responses.aggregations.2.buckets));
                    alert(numbers);
                },`

Comment: try data.reponses[0].aggregations

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
for `(data.responses[0].aggregations.2.buckets)`